# Save/OpenFileDialog freeze the application on Windows

Tags: c#, openfiledialog, savefiledialog

I'm using monodevelop on linux to develop windows Application.  When i try to use my compiled .exe file (compiled on linux) on windows it freeze when Save/OpenFileDialog freeze the application.  On linux works but on windows it doesn't work. Can anyone help me. I can't compile my code on windows becouse the pc where linux is installed is not mine.

Comment: try posting the code and also start by debugging your code since you have direct access to the SRC.

Comment: im actually more surprised that the exe compiled for Linux worked on windows

Comment: I use this: SaveFileDialog save= new SaveDialog(); save.ShowDialog();. In respond to MethodMan's question  the mono framework is designed to develop .NET application in UNIX and WINDOWS system.

Comment: your code needs to go in the section where you posted your original question, edit the question and post all code there.. not in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I correctly understand the question but `SaveFileDialog.ShowDialog()` blocks UI-thread until you select some file to save.

Comment: Yes but when i use this method on linux appears the Save/OpenFileDialog but on windows it stops everythings.

Comment: this should be a comment not an answer since it does not answer the question in regards to fixing the OP's currently stated problem and or Issue..!

Comment: I'm not able to leave a comment however I'm sure that save dialog must be displayed otherwise some exception should be occurred. Looks like some bug in the mono develop compiler.